# how to call non static method from static inner class within same activity

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

```
public class ABC extends Activity{

    public void foo(int val)
    {
    }
    ...
    public static class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ....
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

can anyone help me how can i call `foo()` from `onReceive()` of Receive class

Comment: i already tried ABC ab = new ABC();
ab.foo(5); but it throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: make your foo method static

Comment: not possible because i use progressbar and use thread with sleep()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static YourActivity instance;
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       instance = this;
    }
    ...
    ...
    public void foo() {}

static class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            instance.foo();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I would use a Interface for doing this . Dont use static reference for activity object. It may cause memory leak . Or you should make the static activity reference null on onDestroy method.

Comment: it's will be memory leak.the activity instance  couldn't release。

Answer (score 0):

Move `public void foo(int val)` to Class `Receive`

Comment: how can i use thread.sleep() inside static broadcast receiver class

Comment: why should use thread.sleep()?     handler.sendMessageDelayed()

Answer (score 0):

if you cant make foo method static then you can remove the static from receive class.

```
public class Receive extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: i'm use broadcast receiver for receiving sms